# rspec: How to expect that page has the desired html

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have below html which I took from the launched page source.

```
    <dt title="No. days">No. days:</dt>
    <dd>7</dd>
```

In my test I have to expect the same html, I tried below

```
expect(page.html).to include("<dt title=\"No. days\">No. days:</dt><dd>7</dd>")
```

But got the error.
What format exactly I need to write in the include to expect the same html

Thank you in advance

Comment: You’re conflating data with presentation; this will make the test overly-sensitive to changes. You’re missing a newline and whatever other whitespace may be present.

Comment: I tried even adding new line but did not work out                                           ```expect(page.html).to include("<dt title=\"No. days\">No. days:</dt>\n<dd>7</dd>")```

Comment: "[...] and whatever whitespace may be present." The point is that you're trying to find text in something that isn't *really* text in the end. Treat it as HTML, not text. Better yet, test differently.

Comment: With a debugger, look at `page.html`. Look at what **EXACTLY** the string is. You've presumably made an assumption about how exactly the whitespace is formatted, that's not true. In order to get this test to pass, the expectation needs to perfectly match the generated HTML.

Comment: Or as a *much better* approach, as Dave aid above, it would be better to test this in a different way. For example, you could use a [CSS selector](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FRSpecMatchers:have_css) to look for the `dt` and `dd` elements instead. Or even, perhaps it's overkill to try and test this at the view-level? Could you instead be testing whatever controller/presenter powers this page, to ensure that it contains the expected raw data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is not safe `HTML`.

```
expect(page).to have_selector('dt[title="No. days"]', text: "No. days:")
expect(page).to have_selector('dd', text: "7")
```